# Webdriver: Interact with grid

Tags: c#, webdriver

In order to edit the content of a cell you need to double click on it.  However with webdriver they don't have a doubleclick function in the api. How else can I change the content of the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What grid are you asking about? For most grids there's a JavaScript function to start editing a cell.

Anyway you can fire a double click with a JavaScript. Assuming the the `element` is a `IWebElement` on which you would like to double click:

For the `InternetExplorerDriver`:

```
((IJavascriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(
    "arguments[0].fireEvent('ondblclick')", element);
```

For the `FirefoxDriver` and 'ChromeDriver':

```
((IJavascriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript(
      "var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); evt.initMouseEvent('dblclick'," +
      "true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0," +
      "null); " +
      "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evt);", element);
```

Comment: The grid's class is "x-grid3"

Comment: If it is an ExtJS Grid, then it has a method startEditing( Number rowIndex, Number colIndex ) which can be fired